# Spring Boot 2.0.2 MultipartConfigElement not being configured for MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipart

I'm using Spring Boot **2.0.2.RELEASE**, and not being able to upload files for a REST controller endpoint.

Following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) getting starter, it says:

> As part of auto-configuring Spring MVC, Spring Boot will create a
>   MultipartConfigElement bean and make itself ready for file uploads.

So, theoretically, It should work without any additional configurations, but it looks like this `MultipartConfigElement` is not being configured at all.

I'm getting this warn:

```
WARN .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler: Failed to handle request [POST http://localhost:8080/upload]: Response status 400 with reason "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present"
```

My Spring application starter is as simple as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And my endpoint is:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

@PostMapping("/upload")
public String hash(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    final String test = file.getContentType();
}
```

This is the way I'm sending with postman:
[image]

I also made sure to unmark any default content type set by postman, with no success.
What possibly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you specify any headers in Postman?

Comment: Specifying or not, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Try to set header "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: Already tried that.

Comment: Please list your dependencies. Is spring-boot-starter-web included?

Comment: @fg78nc no, I was using webflux starter. Switching back to web starter solved the problem.

Comment: That's because webflux is not built on servlet, but on netty and accordingly you don't get servlet 3+ multipart support.

Answer (score 0):

First, add this to your properties file

servlet.multipart.enabled=true
servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20M

And create CommonsMultipartResolver bean as 
(name = "multipartResolver")

Comment: Where can I find this in the Spring documentation?

Comment: servlet.multipart.enabled is set to true by default in Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Same question,but I got these files by this way.

You can found these files in this github repository:

[gs-uploading-files](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files)

All you need to do is just download the zip file of this application,and find the files you need.